# mechanism of calling of merge sort algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, recursion, mergesort

1st mergesort function is called till the if condition is satisfied
Now according to my knowledge if  if-conditon is not satisfied then its body will not execute

I m unable to understand after the unsatisfaction of if-conditon 2nd mergesort function is called.so how it happens?
Plz explain in detail

```
mergesort (int*a,int*b,int low,int high)

{

     int  pivot
     if(low<high)
      {
               pivot=(low+high)/2;
               mergesort(a,b,low,pivot);/*1st*/
               mergesort(a,b,pivot+1,high);/*2nd*/
               merge(a,b,low,pivot,high);
       }
     return ;
}
```

Comment: This question doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @AlKepp what did you not understand

Comment: @Ankush You realize that `mergesort` is a function, right?  Q: What happens when a function returns?  A: You proceed to the next evaluation, in this case the next line...

Comment: @pjs oops that was a mistake.Q:did you got my question?

Comment: @Ankush No, it was fine without the explicit return statement.  A function can return by terminating, which is what your algorithm did prior to your edit.

Comment: @pjs  my question is why mergesort(a,b,pivot+1,high) is called?

Comment: @Ankush and my comment was to say "because the call to `mergesort(a,b,low,pivot)` returned here when it was done."

Comment: @Ankush: you need to understand the recursion stack before understanding how merge sort works. In every stack the function called remembers the next line it has to execute when it returns. That is how recursion works.

Comment: @Ankush: Your real question is not clear from the above text. Also, the variable pivot is not a real pivot, the name is wrong and misleading.

Comment: @AlKepp  pivot have the middle index of array

Comment: @Ankush Now I understand what you mean. But this term is wrong, this is terrible English. Pivot is used in Quicksort, it is some kind of a leading item. But you just compute the middle point in the array. It is not even an item of the array, just index of the middle item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow up on Rohlex32's answer (his answer should get credit for the correct answer).

> my question is why mergesort(a,b,pivot+1,high) is called?

As answered by Rohlex32, it's because mergesort(a, b, low, high), uses high as the last index to be sorted, so mergesort(a, b, low, pivot), includes the element at [pivot].

An alternative implementation of mergesort uses a beginning and ending index, where the ending index is 1 greater than the last index. The initial call to mergesort would be

```
mergesort(a, b, 0, sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]));
```

Such a mergesort function would be a bit different than above:

```
void mergesort(int *a, int *b, int begin, int end)
{
    int mid = (begin+end)/2;
    if((end - begin) < 2)
        return;
    mergesort(a, b, begin, mid);    // sort from begin to mid-1
    mergesort(a, b, mid, end);      // sort from mid   to end-1
    merge(a, b, begin, mid, end);   // merge the two parts
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> my question is why mergesort(a,b,pivot+1,high) is called?

mergesort(a,b,pivot+1,high) is called because the prior statement mergesort(a,b,low, pivot) only sorts the lower half and the upper half of the array still needs to be sorted in order for the merge(a, b, low, pivot, high) to be effective (if the sections of the array isn't sorted then .

## For example.

Lets say that you have an array of size 5 {e, d, c, b, a}.

Initially the mergesort(a, b, low, pivot) only sorts from the low point to the pivot **(including the pivot)**, while the mergesort(a, b, pivot+1, high) sorts from the pivot **(not including the pivot)** to the high point.

In the case I supplied this would mean that the first time mergesort was called the pivot would be c. Meaning that {e,b,c} would all be sorted by the 1st mergesort while {b, a} would be sorted by the 2nd mergesort.

For more information see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23059041/7546898)